# I want to bring Lubuntu to the first position and bring Zorin OS to second position in GRUB Menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

So, I installed Zorin OS and now want to bring back my lubuntu to the default position. I am a newbie so please give  a Brief answer I want to bring Lubuntu to the first position and bring Zorin OS to second position in GRUB Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your GRUB.conf is the route to changing your ordered list in grub; but there are easier, more user-friendly ways that won't brick your computer, such as [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).